# Converting weekly data in a table to monthly data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of hours against weeks (start of the week is a Sunday). The weekly data goes up to 12-16 months dependent on user input. I want to create a VBA macro which will iterate through this table of weekly hours data and convert the columns into monthly data.

Example:
All October 2021 related columns will collapse into 1 column called Oct-21. This will also combine the hours. 2nd row in the image below would equal 4+3+4+0= therefore value would be 11 in the new combined column's 2nd row.

My current thinking was calculating the Sundays between the start date and the last date which is below:

```
Dim d As Date, format As String, w As Long, FirstSunday As String
format = format(lastMonth, "Medium Date")
d = DateSerial(Year(format), Month(format), 1)
w = Weekday(d, vbSunday)
FirstSunday = d + IIf(w <> 1, 8 - w, 0)
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

[image: Weekly Data image]

[image: This is the desired output for the new monthly table]

Comment: What exactly does "convert the columns into monthly data" mean? From your question I can understand that you try adding the hours of a specific month (in the header). If my understanding is wrong, please explain what does "2nd row in the image below would equal 4+3+4+0= therefore value would be 11" mean. Then, which is the meaning of each row? Do you want summarizing each row? Do you try summarizing all rows values?

Comment: @FaneDuru Basically I want all the weeks in a month to be combined into 1 column instead of the current format where its 1 column for 1 week. Using October 2021 as a example the first 4 columns being the weeks would combines into just 1 column. All hours in those 4 columns would be added together when combined. That's what i'm after.

Comment: This not involved any conversion... You should summarize all the columns content, based on the column header month (I suppose that the header is formatted as Date). Then, how do you like such a code returning? From your picture we cannot understand on what row is the header. You should tray putting in our shoes when need help...

Comment: @FaneDuru I explained what it was.. It was hours against weeks with each row being a different task. Currently the data is WEEKLY. I want a macro (VBA) to convert the current weekly table into a monthly by combining the week data. It's really not hard to understand the problem..

Comment: @FaneDuru Image 2 shows the desired monthly table after the macro has converted the weekly table to monthly. Row 5 contains the dates. Thanks

Comment: Now I must leave my office. If nobody will answer your question, I will try making a piece of code, after some hours when I will be at home. But I would like to test it and I do not want wasting my time to create a sheet sample looking to your picture... Please share your workbook. Clear it of confidential data, if any. A dummy one. On my personal mail (in my profile), or using a transfer site.

Comment: Why is 31st Oct not included in October ?

Comment: Now I can see your last picture. Where from did you extract now these 'Task #1', 'Task #2` etc.? They cannot be seen in your picture. In such conditions, it is difficult to be helped, I am afraid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you want to group the weeks into months as some months will have 5 weeks. This code inserts a column when the month changes and then fills it with a sum formula for the relevant week columns. It assumes the dates are on row 1 , the task numbers in column 1 and the first week is in column 2.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ByMonth()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    Dim dt As Date

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' scan cols from right to left insert new columns
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For c = LastCol + 1 To 3 Step -1
        ' add columns on month change
        If Month(ws.Cells(1, c)) <> Month(ws.Cells(1, c - 1)) Then
             ws.Columns(c).Insert
             With ws.Columns(c)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                '.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 200)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Cells(1).NumberFormat = "@"
             End With
        End If
    Next

    ' scan left to right filling new cols with sum() formula
    ' hide weekly columns
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    n = 0
    For c = 2 To LastCol + 1
       If ws.Cells(1, c) = "" Then
          dt = ws.Cells(1, c - 1)
          ws.Cells(1, c) = MonthName(Month(dt), True) & "  " & Year(dt)
          ws.Cells(2, c).Resize(LastRow - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-" & n & "]:RC[-1])"
          n = 0
       Else
          ws.Columns(c).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
          n = n + 1
       End If
    Next

    ' copy visible month columns to sheet2
    ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    With wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Activate
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With
      
    ' end
    ws.Columns.Hidden = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: With some editing this was a great solution, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. It assumes that in column A:A, starting from the 6th row, there are (not sorted) tasks. If they are sorted, the code will run without problem, too. It uses arrays and a dictionary and mostly working in memory, should be very fast for big ranges:

```
Sub SumWeeksMonths()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrWk, arrMonths, arrTasks
  Dim i As Long, k As Long, j As Long, El, arr, arrFin, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use there the sheet to be processed
  Set sh1 = sh.Next    'use here the sheet where the processed result to be returned
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row (in column A:A)
  arrWk = sh.Range(sh.Range("B5"), sh.cells(5, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Value 'place the Week headers in a 2D array
  ReDim arrMonths(UBound(arrWk, 2) - 1)'redim the 1D array to keep the unique munths, at a maximum size
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrWk, 2) - 1    'create the array of (only) months:
        If month(DateValue(arrWk(1, i))) <> month(DateValue(arrWk(1, i + 1))) Then
            k = k + 1: arrMonths(k) = Format(DateValue(arrWk(1, i + 1)), "mmm-yyyy")
        Else
            arrMonths(k) = Format(DateValue(arrWk(1, i)), "mmm-yyyy")
        End If
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve arrMonths(k) 'preserve only the existing Date elements
  For Each El In sh.Range("A4:A" & lastR).Value
     dict(El) = 1 'extract the unique tasks (only to count them for ReDim the necessary array)
 Next El
  'place all the range to be processed in an array (for faster iteration):
  arr = sh.Range("A5", sh.cells(lastR, sh.cells(5, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Value
  ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(dict.Keys) + 1, 1 To UBound(arrMonths) + 2) 'reDim the final array to keep processed data
  ReDim arrTasks(UBound(arrMonths))  'redim the array to temporarily keep the array of each task summ
  dict.RemoveAll: k = 0  'clear the dictionary and reitinialize the K variable
  
  For i = 2 To UBound(arr)              'iterate between the main array elements:
     If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then 'if the Task key does not exist:
        For Each El In arrMonths        'iterate between each month in arrMonths:
            For j = 2 To UBound(arr, 2) 'iterate between all arr columns for the i row:
                If month(DateValue(arr(1, j))) = month(El) Then 'if column months is a specific arrMonths column:
                    arrTasks(k) = arrTasks(k) + arr(i, j)               'sumarize everything in the arrTask each element
                End If
         Next j
         k = k + 1                      'increment k, for the next month
       Next El
       dict.Add arr(i, 1), arrTasks     'create the dictionary key with the tasks array as item
       ReDim arrTasks(UBound(arrMonths)): k = 0 'reinitialize arrTasks and k variable
    Else                                        'if dictionary (task) key exists:
        For Each El In arrMonths
            For j = 2 To UBound(arr, 2)
                If month(DateValue(arr(1, j))) = month(El) Then
                    arrTasks(k) = dict(arr(i, 1))(k) + arr(i, j) 'add the sum to the allready existing elements
                End If
         Next j
         k = k + 1
       Next El
       dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrTasks                     'make the item the updaded array
       ReDim arrTasks(UBound(arrMonths)): k = 0       'reinitialize arrTasks and k variable
    End If
  Next i

  'place the processed values in final array (arrFin):
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrMonths) 'firstly the headers:
        arrFin(1, i + 2) = arrMonths(i)
  Next i
  'Extract the tasks value for each month and place in the final array appropriate columns:
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1           'iterate between the dictionary elements:
      arrFin(i + 2, 1) = dict.Keys(i)   'place the task in the array first column, starting from the second row
     For j = 0 To UBound(dict.items(i)) 'iterate between the dictionary item array elements
        arrFin(i + 2, j + 2) = dict.items(i)(j) 'place the appropriate array elements in the final array (arrFin)
     Next j
  Next i
  'drop the final array at once and make some formatting:
  With sh1.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2))
    .Value = arrFin
    With .rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 20
        .BorderAround 1
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .BorderAround 1
 End With
 sh1.Activate 'to see the processing result...
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.