# Converting weekly data in a table to monthly data using VBA for a specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of weekly data to convert into monthly data.

I found [Converting weekly data in a table to monthly data using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449679/converting-weekly-data-in-a-table-to-monthly-data-using-vba) for when the type of item is in column A and the dates start in column B.
I need to use the code for a specified range of columns.

Current Excel Sheet
[image]

The code worked for the most part. The problem is that my system has system generated information in columns B:Q that I am not allowed to delete.

I tried setting a specific range but keep erroring out when it gets to the first non month cell in the bolded section of code.
I tried to change the way the code reads the months but that ended up giving me an error message or skipping months.

How could this work for a specific range R:AC?

```vb
Sub SumByMonth()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    Dim dt As Date
    Dim Myrange As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Myrange = Range("R1:AC1")
    
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

**    **' scan cols from right to left insert new columns
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For c = LastCol + 1 To 3 Step -1
        ' add columns on month change
        If Month(ws.Cells(1, c)) <> Month(ws.Cells(1, c - 1)) Then
             ws.Columns(c).Insert
             With ws.Columns(c)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                '.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 200)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Cells(1).NumberFormat = "@"
             End With
        End If****
    Next

    ' scan left to right filling new cols with sum() formula
    ' hide weekly columns
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    n = 0
    For c = 2 To LastCol + 1
       If ws.Cells(1, c) = "" Then
          dt = ws.Cells(1, c - 1)
          ws.Cells(1, c) = MonthName(Month(dt), True) & "  " & Year(dt)
          ws.Cells(2, c).Resize(LastRow - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-" & n & "]:RC[-1])"
          n = 0
       Else
          ws.Columns(c).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
          n = n + 1
       End If
    Next

     
    ' end
    ws.Columns.Hidden = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

I highlighted the columns for what I'd like it to look like.
[image: This is what it should look like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the hardcoded start column with a Constant

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SumByMonth()

    Const STARTCOL = 18 ' R
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    Dim dt As Date
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
       LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

   ' scan cols from right to left insert new columns
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For c = LastCol + 1 To STARTCOL + 1 Step -1
        ' add columns on month change
        If Month(ws.Cells(1, c)) <> Month(ws.Cells(1, c - 1)) Then
             ws.Columns(c).Insert
             With ws.Columns(c)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                '.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 200)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Cells(1).NumberFormat = "@"
             End With
        End If
    Next

    ' scan left to right filling new cols with sum() formula
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    n = 0
    For c = STARTCOL To LastCol + 1
       If ws.Cells(1, c) = "" Then
            dt = ws.Cells(1, c - 1)
            ws.Cells(1, c) = MonthName(Month(dt), True) & "  " & Year(dt)
            With ws.Cells(2, c).Resize(LastRow - 1)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-" & n & "]:RC[-1])"
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 200)
            End With
            n = 0
       Else
            n = n + 1
       End If
    Next
    
    ' end
    ws.Columns.Hidden = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: that worked perfectly. thank you so much!!! i hadn't heard of using using a constant to shift things like that. I'll definitely read up on it now.